# UHF Rfid to identify people and log time on stand

Tags: rfid

I want to add an uhf reader on every door of a tradeshow that has 4 stands (so it would be 4 doors) so I can log the time that every visitor spends on each stand. The catch is that the uhf tag will be placed on the visitor credential that usually will be placed on the visitors neck. So when he enters a stand I start logging the time and when he leaves I end the log so I can know the time. Which would be the best type of antenna to do this and how should I place it on the door?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to take a look at [Industrial Portals](http://www.industrialportals.com/) catalog by Jamilson . Those are great, and you can get a lot of ideas about how to place the antennas. Further, you are looking for an esthetic solution. So Jamilson catalog has a lot of good looking gates.

If you are looking for a cheaper solution (or faster), you can try one set of [AN200](http://www.barcodediscount.com/catalog/motorola/an200.htm) (one left and one right) from Motorola Symbol.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First; reading all tags at the gate seems really hard because of the Passive Tags. And you can't understand the direction of the person if you can't read all the tags and store this information. If you can't catch 1 of the transaction, you will detect the person direction wrong.

Notes:
* You need to use Circular antenna - because you don't know the exact position of tags.
* More antenna increases reading rate but also harm :(
* Putting antennas with angle to the direction of the walking path is a good solution for reading rates and the tag direction.